# UWPCommunityToolkit Master/Detail view how do I get selected item?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to use Master/Detail from UWPCommunityToolkit, how can I can the details for the selected item? I load the items with a set of anonymous objects:

```
listOfReplayFiles = await ReplayDirectoryManager.GetAllReplaysFromReplayDirectoryAsync();
        foreach (var item in listOfReplayFiles)
        {
            SavedReplays.Add(new { ReplayName = item.Name, ReplayDateCreated = item.DateCreated });
        }
```

This is what my xaml looks like

```
        <uwpkit:MasterDetailsView 
        RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SavedReplays}">

        <uwpkit:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding ReplayName}" />

                    <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}">
                        <Run Text="Date Created: " />
                        <Run Text="{Binding ReplayDateCreated}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </uwpkit:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>

        <!--<uwpkit:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

            </DataTemplate>
        </uwpkit:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>-->

    </uwpkit:MasterDetailsView>
```

I tried adding SelectedItem to xaml with a backing property, but my setter is not triggered when I select items.

Answer (score 0):

> UWPCommunityToolkit Master/Detail view how do I get selected item?

The MasterDetailsView Control presents items in a master/details pattern. It shows a collection of items within the "master panel" and the details for that item within the "details panel".

So that the details panel will show the current selected item. What you just need is to bind your details of this item to the `DetailsTemplate`. For example, show the same content within details panel as master panel has may as follows:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <uwpkit:MasterDetailsView 
    RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <uwpkit:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding ReplayName}" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}">
                    <Run Text="Date Created: " />
                    <Run Text="{Binding ReplayDateCreated}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </uwpkit:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
        <uwpkit:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding ReplayName}" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}">
                    <Run Text="Date Created: " />
                    <Run Text="{Binding ReplayDateCreated}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </uwpkit:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
    </uwpkit:MasterDetailsView>
</Grid>
```

More dertails please reference the [MasterDetailsView sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/MasterDetailsView).

Comment: I need there to be extra processing when I select an item, so I can't have the same object for master and for detail, or my app will be very slow.

Comment: Did you mean the master and detail use different items source on your side? @haosmark

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I also want the same thing.

Comment: @haosmark If you have found a way to do it, Please answer your post